# Shuffling a vector using std::shuffle slows down multiplication using for - loop

Tags: c++, shuffle

I am multiplying a 2D std::vector **v** row-wise (leaving out the zeroth entry in every row) with a 1D std::vector **weights_v**. If I shuffle the rows of **v** (using **std::shuffle**) prior to multiplication, the multiplicative loop takes more time to finish. This makes me wonder about the effect of shuffling. Does shuffling actually change the ordering of the data in memory, or does it merely create a map linking the shuffled indices to the data locations, which stay unchanged?

I use the following command to compile my program:

```
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -march=native temp3.cc -o t3 -std=c++17
```

The time it takes to finish the for loop without the shuffling is:

```
cpp:Pro$ ./t3
loop time is 163.097 ms
```

and when shuffling is done, the time is:

```
cpp:Pro$ ./t3
loop time is 250.213 ms
```

What could be the reason behind this behaviour?

**Edit**: I checked the pointer address of a random element before and after the shuffle, and they are indeed different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> v(10000);
    std::vector<double> weights_v(784);
    std::vector<uint8_t> y_v(10000), t_v(10000);

    std::minstd_rand rd(100); //initialising and seeding the rng
    std::uniform_int_distribution dist_int_0_255(0, 255); //will generate ints between 0 and 255 
    std::uniform_int_distribution dist_int_0_1(0, 1);//will generate ints 0 and 1
    std::uniform_real_distribution dist_real(-1, 1);//will generate real numbers between -1 and 1 

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 785; j++) {
            v[i].push_back(dist_int_0_255(rd));//populating the 2D vector
        }
    }

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < weights_v.size(); i++) {
        weights_v[i] = dist_real(rd); //populating the weights vector
    }

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < y_v.size(); i++) {
        y_v[i] = dist_int_0_1(rd);//filling the predicted and target vectors with random 0s and 1s
        t_v[i] = dist_int_0_1(rd);
    }

    int err, T;
    T = 100;
    double eta = 0.25;
    double sum_wx_v;

    //if I comment out the next two lines, the multiplicative loop (LOOP_1) runs faster
    std::mt19937 g(50);
    std::shuffle(std::begin(v), std::end(v), g);

    auto start2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); //start of LOOP_1
    
    for (int iter = 0; iter < T; iter++) {//LOOP_1
        for(unsigned long j = 0; j < v.size(); j++) {
            sum_wx_v = 0.0;
            for (unsigned long k = 1; k < v[0].size() ; k++) {
                sum_wx_v += weights_v[k - 1] * v[j][k];
            }

            //some code to update y_v[i] based on the value of sum_wx_v which I left out

            err = y_v[j] - t_v[j];
            if (fabs(err) > 0) {
                for (unsigned long k = 1; k < v[0].size(); k++) {
                    weights_v[k - 1] -= eta * err * v[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    auto end2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto diff2 = end2 - start2;
    std::cout << "loop time is "<<std::chrono::duration <double, std::milli> (diff2).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @NateEldredge I checked the pointer values before and after the shuffle, and it outputs different addresses.

Comment: Okay, so that suggests that indeed pointers are being moved.  If all the data was being copied then the address of `v[i][j]` would not change.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not so sure about that, this could also be achieved by just mapping the indices to different memory locations, right?

Comment: `std::shuffle` uses `std::swap` on the elements of the range. In this case, those elements are vectors, and would be swapped via the move assignment. The actual `uint8_t` data will stay put, only the pointers to it (inside the vectors) will be swapped around.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so that confirms my hypotheses it seems?

Comment: What is your hypothesis? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I believe that the data is not being moved around, it's only the indices point to different locations, and unlike the original vector, this time  consecutive vector elements would not be consecutive in memory, which causes the slow execution

Comment: The data in each row would be consecutive in memory: `v[j][k]` is guaranteed to be next to `v[j][k+1]`. The individual rows indeed wouldn't be consecutive to each other: `v[j][0]` would not be next to `v[j+1][0]`. They weren't next to each other before the shuffle either - they are in independently allocated blocks of memory.  But perhaps they were nearby, simply by accident of implementation of the heap manager.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oh yes, I meant the rows won't be consecutive. Now I understand that they weren't concecutive earlier too but the shuffle basically makes it worse.

Comment: If you want to physically shuffle actual row data, you could use `std::vector<std::array<uint8_t, 785>>`. This way, when you shuffle the vector, the actual data will move around.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, though I will have to check whether it makes the code faster or not

Comment: Something that takes minutes to do on the CPU could take seconds on the GPU if you're looking for a real performance boost here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I did as you suggested and now it's as fast as it is without shuffling

Comment: @tadman I sure am looking for the best performance that I can get on available hardware. Though I currently don't have a GPU, I am very interested in learning about it :)

Comment: @tadman Infact, I am also using the Eigen library to see if it helps, but Eigen matrix multiplication is not consistently fast than this basic implementation multiplying vectors, atleast on my 2012 macbook pro

Comment: The  problem you encountered here (data blocks not being adjacent to each other) is basically eliminated if you keep the entire 2D matrix in a 1D vector. This is implemented in basically every multi-dimensional array library (e.g. Eigen). It introduces new complexities, but it is definitly the right way to do it if you're worried about performance. It is also the first step you'll have to take if you want to solve this on a GPU.